# Is there a mysql "multitable" trigger - E.G. a trigger that fires only after ALL tables are done updating?

Tags: mysql, sql, json

[image: Rough schema]
several tables have a trigger that generates a json object representations of the row on update/insert. E.G. `{"email": ..., "relations: N" } //<--an email.json column` and stores it in a json column

relations is simply a numeric tie-together (let me know if there is a word for it) that allows me to tie together multiple names, emails, phones, homes into one object -

E.G. `the touchRelation.json column`

```
{ 
"emails": [ {"email": 1@a.com },{"email:  2@a.com"},{"email:  N@a.com"}],
"teles" : [ {"tele" : ... },{"tele : ...."},{"tele : ...."}],
"Names" : [ {"Name" : ... },{"Name : ...."},{"Name : ...."}],
"Homes" : [ {"Home" : ... },{"Home : ...."},{"Home : ...."}],
}
```

The problem I'm having is that 1) it would be wasteful and inefficient to update touchRelations.json EVERY TIME one of the other tables gets data CRUD, especially if several tables are updated at one time

2) I may not be able to rely on the developer to call an update_Relations_json() after each query.

Is there a simple way tell if one or more of the tables have been updated and ONLY regenerate relations.json after all updates on all tables have finished?

---

One Possible Solution would be to create a "pending Updates" table that stores the information in a queue and one by one inserts/updates the data from the queue table to the storage table then calls the update function, but I'm sure this isn't the best option.

Another option would be to create a JSON parser in the db that reads the complete json relation (the big one from above), updates the tables then builds the json object, but that seems like a poor use of the database.

Comment: +1 for Good Question.I don't know solution for this, but just for an IDEA, if you know which table is updated last then, you can create trigger for that table only.

Comment: Maybe use transactions for such updates, and have a trigger run at `commit transaction`?

Comment: Don't know if it's the best, but I would probably create a table with the names of all tables and some sort of control (already updated or not).

Comment: This is where stored procedures are used. Create the procedure that calls your code in the end and remove the permissions to directly update the tables - thus forcing the developer to always call the procedure instead.

Comment: a stored procedure wouldn't solve the problem because the procedures would be table specific (e.g. update_phones(phone number) ) or they would be unwieldy {e.g. update_all_tables_and_generate_json(everything_here, including_random, numbers_of_homes, phones, etc) ugly}

Comment: @Vesper: I don't think MySQL supports triggers that are fired on commit.

Comment: I the JSON document is always completely based on the content in the database, wouldn't it be better to generate the JSON "on-the-fly" when selecting, e.g. in a view? Although MySQL has not JSON support whatsoever it might still be doable through a function.

Comment: Good question - the json IS always based on the contents of the DB, HOWEVER, I request the data many times more often than I insert it. Also, I have MANY requests for the data at any given time, it would kill my server to generate complex json objects on the fly thousands of times when I can do it once and not worry about it again for six months.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name Indeed. Maybe then do a dummy action on a separated table that will have the desired trigger attached, right after `commit transaction`?

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name I am using the json udf library found at http://www.mysqludf.org/ to provide semi-native json support for DB

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image]
The BEST option I can think of would be to create an "updates" meta-data column with a default of 0. When we update the phone, email, name, or home the meta-data column is changed to 1 (representing that an update was not committed to the relations JSON column)

Next create a stored procedure "request_relations_json()" that checks for pending commits (a 1 in the "updates" meta-column). IF there are no updates, return the current relations.json column to the application. If there are updates, regenerate the json then return it to the application.

It's hackish, but it isn't generating json on every update. I still hope there's a more elegant solutions out there.

Comment: Later on i changed to couchdb and couldn't be more thrilled. Its beautiful and easy and i t saves so much time when i change the schema.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this is an answer or a comment, but...

MySQL doesn't support transaction triggers. This means that you can only fire triggers when data is changed in a table. In your example, I'm guessing there is no pre-defined order or combination for the data changes - in one case, you might be creating a brand new record, complete with email, address, name and phone; in another case, you might be adding a new phone number to an existing record.

Having a "trigger per table" is the only way in which you can achieve what you want without resorting to exotic solutions (like [mimicking a materialized view](http://www.fromdual.com/mysql-materialized-views)).

However, as you are already storing your data 3 times (once in the "normal" columns, once in the table JSON, once in the relations JSON), is efficiency really such a big deal? Do you *know* this is a problem?

A bigger concern for me is that I dislike triggers on principle - they're hard to test, harder to debug, and harder still to maintain in an evolving database. 
Triggers that act on data or tables outside the current row make me very nervous - testing the different permutations of insert/update/delete on your 4 tables would be extremely hard - what if the trigger on "touchEmail" has a bug that overwrites the data managed by the trigger on "touchHome"? You may also face deadlocks etc. (not sure if that's a realistic concern on MySQL).

Have you considered using a different cache for your JSON? There are a number of options. MySQL has a [query cache](http://www.petefreitag.com/item/390.cfm); if you can rely on this, you would create the JSON on the fly, and cache the queries. This has the huge benefit of dealing with cache invalidation automagically - as the underlying data changes, MySQL purges the relevant items in the cache. On the downside - tuning this cache is tricky.

The next option is whatever your programming language/framework gives you. Most modern frameworks include a solution for caching, but you almost certainly end up invalidating the cache in code; this can be a complex solution, but puts the responsibility where it belongs (the application developers).

If your solution has to scale to exotic levels, you can use a dedicated cache - [memcache](http://memcached.org/) is available for most environments and languages. It works, scales, is robust - but also introduces significant additional complexity.

Comment: I understand triggers can be a nightmare - however, part of our design pattern is to separate the database, as completely as possible, from the developer/application.

Comment: The data-redundancy issue is atypical. clearly the data is stored 3 times - the thing that makes this different is that while we may input to (almost) ANY table, we only request from ONE. It's also a very linear path from table_column->table_json->relation_json. each step is clearly distinguishable from the previous. Making normalization/troubleshooting fairly simple.

Comment: I haven't really considered a different a cache other than a native json no-sql database.  But I'm not familiar enough with no-sql databases to make an informed decision. Suggestions?